# Handling garbage collection in Java program while producing a lot of garbage

Tags: java

I have programmed a Jigsaw Puzzle which uses a BufferedImage for each piece. This is done because it has a specifc shadow and marking on it.
When I combine two pieces, I created a new BufferedImage, paint the two pieces on it, and throw all references to the old images away.
My problem is that during solving a puzzle with many pieces like 100 or so, the program seems to pile up more and more memory without running a garbage collection, and when it finally decides to clean up, it runs out of memory because the remaining free memory was too little for the garbage collection to run.
Is there any way I can tell the garbage collection to collect garbage more often and during a course of the game instead of waiting until the very last moment ?

Comment: It sounds like you may actually have a leak rather than anything else - it shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may still hold indirect references to the BufferedImage. For example:

```
Graphics g = bufferedImg.createGraphics();
bufferedImg = null;
// you still have an indirect reference through the graphics object g!
```

Also, there may be native resources allocated with BufferedImage and/or its Graphics, which can (depending on the JRE implementation) delay the garbage collection of these objects. You can hint the JRE to release these resources by calling Graphics.dispose() and BufferedImage.flush().

Answer (score 1):

Only objects which aren't referenced anywhere are eligible for GC. Since GC will **always** run right before the JVM dies with an `OutOfMemoryError`, this means that you're still referencing memory-hogging objects in the currently running code scope. The solution is simple: stop referencing them when you don't need them or give the JVM more memory for the case that you *really* need them.